# Parity all pending transactions (not local)

Tags: parity, pending-transactions

From some version of Parity, it began to start like this

[image]

And now, when i try to get all pending transactions from the whole pool, i'm getting only these local. But i need to get ALL as earlier. How to do it?

```
web3.eth.subscribe('pendingTransactions', (e, r) => {
if (!e) {
    console.log(r);
}
```

});

Answer (score -1):

`pendingTransactions` will only return the pending txs for your addresses.

If you want to get all unmined transactions on the node, you want the `txpool_contents` API.

Comment: Thx. But before it returned all unmined transactions. What has changed?

Comment: txpool_contents is only for geth, question is for parity